# Editable textbox on click, angular.js

Tags: django, angularjs

in my project I have a list of project names and I'd like to edit the names with dynamic textboxes using angular.js. I'd like the textboxes of my projects names to become editable if I click on a button next to my project titles, and confirm the edition with another button when I'm done typing. Can I do such thing with angular.js ? I just finished the tutorial and am quite noob with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actualy it is one of my most favorite example when I am doing AngularJS presentations to public :)

There is a code without single line of JS code:
http://plnkr.co/edit/ZwYA6R2e6kdhHBJAYf3V?p=preview

```
  <span ng-hide="editing">
    {{name}} <button ng-click="editing = true">Edit</button>
  </span>
  <span ng-show="editing">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name"> 
    <button ng-click="editing = false">Save</button>
  </span>
```

Comment: Well, I'm a lucky guy you saw my question :) I'm testing it, will tell you if everything's fine there.

Comment: All right this is perfect. Now I need to import in my js var name my projects list so I can use my projects name in the editing field. Then I need to save the modified model in Django. Is that possible ? :D

Comment: And also, I need to dissociate my several projects. Right now, when I click an edit button, every single project swaps to edit view. Can I fix this ? Edit : nevermind, I found a way to do this ! :) But my question before is still without any answer, if you know how to do that, please tell me ! :)

Comment: Just put them into separate child scopes. A tiny directive that creates new child scope can help you (for example like an attribute 'child-scope' on element that separates your projects, e.g. ```<div ... child-scope ng-repeat="project in projects"> ...project line </div>```.